# Meaning of `cat /dev/null > file`

Tags: shell, files, io-redirection, cat, null

In a document created by a former coworker there is this command:

```
cat /dev/null > /var/spool/mail/root
```

It says next to it that it will clean out mailbox.

Can someone please explain how/why these commands do that. I need to know what will happen before I run the command.

We are trying to clean up space on var, as of right now it's at 91%.

Comment: It basically truncates `/var/spool/mail/root`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The command will output the data from device `/dev/null` to the given file (mailbox of the root account). Since `/dev/null` responds just with end-of-file when reading from it nothing will be written to the file, but with the redirection `>` the shell will have cleared the file already. Actually this is equivalent to writing just

```
> /var/spool/mail/root
```

(i.e., the same without `cat` or `/dev/null`).

Comment: another alternative (that is probably clearer) `truncate -s 0 /var/spool/mail/root`.

Answer (score 3):

`cat /dev/null > /var/spool/mail/root`  truncates `/var/spool/mail/root`

Alternative is `> /var/spool/mail/root`

Comment: Is there a way I can get all the mail from this and put it somewhere where it can be downloaded and archived as a backup?

Comment: Just copy that file `/var/spool/mail/root`